# Validating emails with RCTP TO over TLS - receiving status 250 even for invalid email addresses

Tags: validation, email, ssl, smtp, smtplib

I am currently developing an email validation tool in Python that establishes an SMTP connection with an MX server from the email's domain and checks the deliverability of the email address with the RCPT TO command.

This works pretty well, but now comes the problem:
To enable a secure verification process I want to run the verification over a **TLS connection**.
In order to do that, I chose a fix SMTP hostserver for connection establishment (e.g. smtp.gmail.com) and then authenticate the client with an email address known to the server (e.g. a gmail address).

The problem is that now I always receive (250, b'2.1.5 OK ... - gsmtp') even if I know the email to be invalid.

What could be the issue here?

- The fact of using TLS?
- The fact of not using an MX server of the email domain to verify?
- The fact of always using the same server?
- Or something else?

Happy to get some hints and general recommendations on how to develop a robust implementation of the specific service.

**What worked**
Lets say I have an email address xyz@somedomain.com. I verify mydomain.com, I connect to one of the MX servers of mydomain.com (without TLS) and issue the RCPT TO command.
Here I receive a correct feedback.

**What didnt work**
I want to validate an email address xyz@somedomain.com. I therefore establish a TLS connection with smtp.gmail.com by authenticating the client with the source mail someemail@gmail.com. I issue the RCPT TO command for the email address xyz@somedomain.com and receive **wrong feedback** (status 250 eventhough the email address doesnt exist).

Comment: When you connect to gmail but want to send to example.com, gmail has no way of knowing whether the address is valid or not. Since you authenticated to gmail, it accepts your recipient address. It's like you emailing someone in e.g. Thunderbird with gmail as your email service. Gmail will only find out when it actually tries to deliver whether that email address exists. This has nothing to do with TLS. Gmail will probably reject an example.com address if you're not authenticated so that spammers can't misuse gmail (gmail isn't an open relay).

Comment: The bigger question is: what are you trying to do? If you want people to sign up for your service, I'd send a confirmation email with a link where people confirm they want to sign up (double opt-in; this is the industry standard). That way you're sure the email exists, gets read, and the person actually wants to use your service. It gets rid of all the extra work you seem to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the information - I just find it weird that gmail does return anything at all (250) if it actually doesn't know anything about the email. Concerning the purpose: Im trying to develop an email verification service.

Comment: @robert And maybe something to add which was not clear enough: I use an actual existing gmail-address as source address and to log myself in at gmail.

Comment: What you are doing is called relaying. You are logged in to gmail. So gmail knows you're not a random spammer. Gmail accepts the address and tries to relay to it. To check if it does actually exist, you must connect to the server that actually handles email for that domain, as you found out. But servers may try to block you if you try a bunch of email addresses, as spammers did that to make sure addresses were valid. I'd again suggest you skip this and go with double opt-in.

Comment: @Robert I understand and am a bit surprised about all the email verification services out there e.g. [neverbounce](https://www.neverbounce.com/). Out of curiosity, I guess these services use their own SMTP servers to connect to the SMTP server of the specific domain? How can they assure a secure connection?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. Maybe they have enough IP addresses (or VPNs) to rotate through so that it doesn't break them when they get blocked. Or maybe they got on the allow list of the big email providers and are allowed to check that email addresses exist. There is also [SMTP VRFY](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-3.5) but AFAIK most server's don't support it. See also the [vrfy](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/vrfy.1.html) tool.

Comment: @robert Yes, I already included SMTP VRFY to check in parallel what it gives back. Thanks anyways for your helpful answers!